# WPF and XPS: Empty Document Viewer

Tags: wpf, xps, xpsdocument

```
        byte[] mediaBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("<<strings>>");

        XpsDocument doc;

        ms = new MemoryStream(mediaBytes, 0, mediaBytes.Length);

        Uri DocumentUri = new Uri("pack://document.xps");

        using (Package package = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create))
        {
            PackageStore.AddPackage(DocumentUri, package);
            doc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, DocumentUri.AbsoluteUri);
            FixedDocumentSequence fds = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            documentViewer.Document = fds as IDocumentPaginatorSource;
            PackageStore.RemovePackage(DocumentUri);
            doc.Close();
        }
```

Can anyone please help me. Its result is an empty document. The mediaBytes is a PDF document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your statement:  Package package = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create)
You are setting ms as the package destination stream, not a source stream.

Comment: When you step thru the code, what do you get for fds?  Do you get an object or null?

Comment: See the code at this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/48043d53-f552-4869-8d93-8060ba2ab898